# Including multiple dict<> in a plist for Localization

Tags: ios, objective-c, localizable.strings

I cannot include multiple dict-key as shown below.It works fine when i include just one key value.

```
 <plist version="1.0">
              <dict>
                <key>%d people are in the room</key>
                <dict>
                  <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
                  <string>%#@num_people_in_room@ in the room</string>
                  <key>num_people_in_room</key>
                  <dict>
                    <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
                    <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
                    <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
                    <string>d</string>
                    <key>zero</key>
                    <string>No one is</string>
                    <key>one</key>
                    <string>A person is</string>
                    <key>two</key>
                    <string>Two people are</string>
                    <key>other</key>
                    <string>%d people are</string>
                  </dict>
                </dict>
              </dict>

      <dict>
        <key>He scored %d runs</key>
        <dict>
          <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
          <string>He scored %#@run_or_runs@</string>
          <key>run_or_runs</key>
          <dict>
            <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
            <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
            <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
            <string>d</string>
            <key>zero</key>
            <string>no run</string>
            <key>one</key>
            <string>%d run</string>
            <key>other</key>
            <string>%d runs</string>
          </dict>
        </dict>
      </dict>
    </plist>
```

removing one of the dicts, gives me the desired result. What am i doing wrong here?
How do i include multiple string keys?

Answer (score 1):

When using a plist, you must set the root item to be an array if you want to hold a list of items, and then each item in the array is a dictionary. To use a dictionary as the root you would need to give each item it's own key. You can't just add arbitrary contents to the file as it has a tightly defined format.

In this case, the root should be a dictionary which has multiple keys. Each key has a dictionary as its value.

From a text editing perspective in your file, remove `</dict><dict>` so you don't complete and start a new dictionary but just add to the root dictionary.

Comment: made array as the root. but localising the string doesn't work.   NSString* string = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"%d people are in the room", nil), 1];